# How to change the option list dynamically in ui-selectable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a web site coded in javascript and jquery. I have a list of options created with a [jQuery-ui `selectable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) which will change when a button is clicked (button containing a javascript code). Below some of my code:

Fist, my ui-selectable code...

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        stop: function(){
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function(){
                var seq = $(this).text(); //data -> selected sequence
                showdata(seq); //TODO when sequence is selected
            });
        }
    });
```

Here, my code to build a set of options which will be called when a button is clicked...

```
function showS2P(){
    var s = '';
    s = s + "<div class=\"listS2P\" align=\"left\">";
    //document.write(arrS2P.length); //show number of patterns per selected zone
    if (arrS2P.length == 0) {
        s = s + "Any pattern found";
    } else {
        s = s + "<ul id=\"selectable\">";
        for (var i=0; i<arrS2P.length; i++){
            s = s + "<li class=\"ui-widget-conten\">"+arrS2P[i]+"</li>";
            //document.write("<h3> "+i+" -> "+arrS2P[i]+"</h3> <br/>");
        }
        s = s + "</ul>";
    }
    s = s + "</div>";
    document.getElementById('selectSeq').innerHTML = s; //selectSeq is a <div> which change when a button is clicked
    $(selectable).selectmenu("refresh");
}
```

Currently, when I click my button, the options are shown in a `<div>`, but as plain text (ie, it is not possible to click on options). Please, does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: is the last line, `$(selectable).selectmenu("refresh")`, meant to be `$("#selectable").selectmenu("refresh")`?

Comment: Hi Will... yes but I think that I don't need this line. I'm really new in Jquery.

Comment: That would indeed be the line which "refreshes" your list of options. That said, according to [the documentation for Selectmenu](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu) (scroll down to "Add / delete / modify options"), the proper call is actually `$("#selectable).selectmenu();`, with no argument.

As a side-note, I would avoid using plain javascript such as `document.write` or `document.getElementById(...)` when using jQuery, as consistency is always easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

To add action on click event you need write next:

```
$("#selectSeq option").live("click",function(){
   // Here do something
   var val = $(this).val(); // value of option;
   var text = $(this).html(): // text of option;
});
```

*// PS: instead '#selectSeq' you can use another id of select or another selector of list.*

Comment: `.live` has been superceded by `.on` as of jQuery 1.7, you should not recommend it in new code.

Comment: Thanks Barmar... As additional information, when I load my page, **ui-selectable** works fine but the problem is when I try to change the **option list** using `document.getElementById('selectSeq').innerHTML`

Comment: Hi again Petro, I have the same problem, I suppose that I put your code into my **button** and `var val = $(this).val();` and `var text = $(this).html();` will change when the user push the button. Sorry but I'm new in JQuery and javascript.